# How to handle an index out of bounds error?

Tags: error-handling, rust, runtime-error

What is the idiomatic way to handle this to avoid a runtime error:

```
let address = match x[1].parse::<String>() {
    Ok(a) => Some(a),
    Err(_) => None,
};
```

Where `x[1]` could panic with an `index out of bounds` error?

Answer (score 9):

You could use `get` See: [Slice documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get).

```
let address: Option<String> = x.get(1).and_then(|v| {
    v.parse().ok()
});
```